# Formulating a query for people not in a relationship

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a model where users can play multiple games (many to many), and each user 
can be in one or many teams (many to many). Each team is associated with a particular game.

I'd like to extract all the people who are not currently in a particular team for a particular game E.g. who is not in team 2, and can play game 5

The model looks like...

```
Player
    id

Player_Game
    player_id
    game_id

Game
    game_id

Team
    id
    game_id

Team_Player
    team_id
    player_id
```

I've played around with the SQL for 1/2 a day now, and not getting anywhere fast.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have your tried so far? A sample of the data and structure and desired output will help

Comment: Did you try the straight-forward `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` (or `IN` and `NOT IN` for that matter)? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you have given, you could use the following statement;

```
SELECT 
    p.id
,   pg.game_id
,   tp.team_id 
FROM Player p
INNER JOIN
    Player_Game pg
    ON p.id = pg.player_id
INNER JOIN
    Team_Player tp
    ON p.id = tp.player_id
WHERE tp.team_id != 2 --!= donates not equal to change the team ID to strip out teams out of your search
AND pg.game_id IS NULL --if the player is not in a game then this value will not be set
```

I have made a couple of assumptions in regards to your model, so if a person is not in a game then the game id value will be NULL. if this is incorrect then my solution would not work

The above statement would return all players where the team id is not 2.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: With "INNER JOIN Player_Game pg", you can't have " pg.game_id IS NULL", so basically your query is false

Comment: but I'm joining on the player ID? so as long as they are both the same it will return the player id's game id value? as said I've made the assumption that the pg.game_id wouldn't be set if they are not in a game? But re reading the question I think I've misunderstood the 'Can play game 5' part and as you've put in your answer, the game_id would be set to 5 to indicate thats the game they want to play

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select P.id, T.team_id from
Player P 
left outer join Team_Player T on T.player_id=P.id
inner join Player_Game G on G.player_id=P.id
where T.team_id<>2 and G.game_id=5
```

You can read about Inner joins from here: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/inner-join-with-multiple-tables.php
and Outer joins from here:
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/left-join.php